How to get faster output with Spark Structured Streaming?
I would like to calculate the average of a variable over a sliding window. Although my code works, it is tremendously slow before I see any output. Consequently, this output comes mostly in bursts several minutes later.
I don't mind a latency of a few seconds at all, but a few minutes is really long...
Does anyone have an idea how I can improve this?
# Build Session & get data from a calculation
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, from_json, window, current_timestamp, to_json, struct, lit, unix_timestamp, avg, collect_list, from_unixtime, date_format
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, DoubleType, StringType

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .master("local") \
    .appName("Nats Jetstream Concept") \
    .config("spark.logConf", "true") \
    .config("spark.jars", 
            "./nats-spark-connector/load_balanced/target/scala-2.12/nats-spark-connector-balanced-assembly-1.2.2.jar," 
            +"./Nats_Spark_Connector_Scala/jnats-2.13.2.jar") \
    .config("spark.executor.instances", "6") \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "2g") \
    .config("spark.cores.max", "12") \
    .getOrCreate()

schema = StructType([
    StructField("subject", StringType(), True),
    StructField("datetime", StringType(), True),
    StructField("content", StringType(), True)
])

input_df = spark.readStream.format("nats") \
    .option("nats.host", "nats-server") \
    .option("nats.port", "4222") \
    .option("nats.stream.name", "CalculationStream") \
    .option("nats.stream.subjects", "calc.averagewindow.input") \
    .option("nats.msg.ack.wait.secs", 90) \
    .option("nats.num.listeners", 1) \
    .option("nats.msg.fetch.batch.size", 1) \
    .option("nats.durable.name", "SparkConsumer") \
    .schema(schema) \
    .load()
# define json schema of content
json_schema = StructType([
    StructField("A", DoubleType(), False),
    StructField("timestamp_produced", DoubleType(), False)
])
# parse the json and transform datetime to timestamp
parsed_df = input_df \
    .withColumn("json", from_json(col("content"), json_schema)) \
    .withColumn("timestamp_produced", (col("json.timestamp_produced").cast("bigint") / 1000).cast("timestamp")) \
    .withColumn("A", col("json.A")) \
    .withColumn("timestamp_nats", (unix_timestamp(col("datetime"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS") * 1000))
parsed_df.printSchema()

window_df = parsed_df \
    .withWatermark("timestamp_produced", "30 seconds") \
    .groupBy(
        window(col("timestamp_produced"), "5 seconds", "3 seconds"),
    ).agg(
        avg('A').alias("average_A"),
        # collect_list("timestamp_produced").alias("timestamp_produced_list"),
        # collect_list("timestamp_nats").alias("datetime_nats_list")
    )
window_df.printSchema()
output_df = window_df \
    .withColumn(
        "json_output",
        to_json(
            struct(
                col("window.start"),
                col("window.end"),
                col("average_A"),
                # col("timestamp_produced_list"),
                # col("datetime_nats_list")
            )
        )
    ) \
    .withColumn("subject", lit("calc.averagewindow.spark_out")) \
    .withColumn("timestamp_transformed", date_format(current_timestamp(), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")) \
    .select(col("subject"),col("timestamp_transformed"),col("json_output"))

output_df.printSchema()

# output to nats jetstream
output_df.writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("nats") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "./spark_checkpoint") \
    .option("nats.host", "nats-server") \
    .option("nats.port", "4222") \
    .trigger(processingTime="1 seconds") \
    .start() \
    .awaitTermination()

The output looks as follows with the values produced and the results from Spark, respectively.
You can see the output follows in bursts after a few minutes.
...
[20:59:24 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":3,"timestamp_produced":1712084363949}
[20:59:27 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":41,"timestamp_produced":1712084366952}
[20:59:30 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":87,"timestamp_produced":1712084369958}
[20:59:33 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":38,"timestamp_produced":1712084372962}
[20:59:35 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":80,"timestamp_produced":1712084374964}
[20:59:37 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":20,"timestamp_produced":1712084376967}
[20:59:39 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":62,"timestamp_produced":1712084378974}
[20:59:41 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":14,"timestamp_produced":1712084380977}
[20:59:43 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":58,"timestamp_produced":1712084382981}
[20:59:45 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":56,"timestamp_produced":1712084384986}
[20:59:47 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":91,"timestamp_produced":1712084386988}
[20:59:49 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":32,"timestamp_produced":1712084388995}
[20:59:51 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":50,"timestamp_produced":1712084390996}
[20:59:53 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":47,"timestamp_produced":1712084393001}
[20:59:55 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":21,"timestamp_produced":1712084395006}
[20:59:57 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":55,"timestamp_produced":1712084397014}
[20:59:59 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":45,"timestamp_produced":1712084399022}
[21:00:01 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":51,"timestamp_produced":1712084401028}
[21:00:03 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":43,"timestamp_produced":1712084403031}
[21:00:05 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":0,"timestamp_produced":1712084405035}
[21:00:07 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":44,"timestamp_produced":1712084407039}
[21:00:09 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":23,"timestamp_produced":1712084409045}
[21:00:11 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":28,"timestamp_produced":1712084411055}
[21:00:13 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":12,"timestamp_produced":1712084413062}
[21:00:15 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":39,"timestamp_produced":1712084415081}
[21:00:17 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":30,"timestamp_produced":1712084417096}
[21:00:19 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":60,"timestamp_produced":1712084419100}
[21:00:21 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":99,"timestamp_produced":1712084421102}
[21:00:23 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":29,"timestamp_produced":1712084423106}
[21:00:25 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":97,"timestamp_produced":1712084425110}
[21:00:27 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":50,"timestamp_produced":1712084427112}
[21:00:29 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":18,"timestamp_produced":1712084429114}
[21:00:31 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":11,"timestamp_produced":1712084431117}
[21:00:33 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":14,"timestamp_produced":1712084433120}
[21:00:35 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":42,"timestamp_produced":1712084435122}
[21:00:37 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":71,"timestamp_produced":1712084437126}
[21:00:39 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":2,"timestamp_produced":1712084439131}
[21:00:41 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":56,"timestamp_produced":1712084441137}
[21:00:43 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":24,"timestamp_produced":1712084443139}
[21:00:45 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":34,"timestamp_produced":1712084445142}
[21:00:47 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":7,"timestamp_produced":1712084447144}
[21:00:49 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":33,"timestamp_produced":1712084449147}
[21:00:51 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":15,"timestamp_produced":1712084451152}
[21:00:53 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":43,"timestamp_produced":1712084453176}
[21:00:55 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":3,"timestamp_produced":1712084455182}
[21:00:57 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":71,"timestamp_produced":1712084457185}
[21:00:59 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":57,"timestamp_produced":1712084459187}
[21:01:01 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"A":52,"timestamp_produced":1712084461189}
[21:01:01 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:55:24.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:55:29.000Z","average_A":88.0}
[21:01:01 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:56:09.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:14.000Z","average_A":96.0}
[21:01:01 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:55:12.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:55:17.000Z","average_A":33.0}
[21:01:01 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:55:18.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:55:23.000Z","average_A":41.0}
[21:01:01 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:56:06.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:11.000Z","average_A":5.0}
[21:01:01 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:56:51.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:56.000Z","average_A":59.0}
[21:01:01 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:55:48.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:55:53.000Z","average_A":55.0}
[21:01:01 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:55:36.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:55:41.000Z","average_A":44.0}
[21:01:01 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:55:15.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:55:20.000Z","average_A":93.0}
[21:01:01 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:56:12.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:17.000Z","average_A":81.0}
[21:01:01 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:55:21.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:55:26.000Z","average_A":76.0}
[21:01:01 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:55:51.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:55:56.000Z","average_A":86.0}
[21:01:01 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:55:09.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:55:14.000Z","average_A":57.0}
[21:01:01 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:56:00.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:05.000Z","average_A":99.0}
[21:01:01 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:56:42.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:47.000Z","average_A":5.0}
[21:01:01 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:56:30.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:35.000Z","average_A":6.0}
[21:01:01 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:56:39.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:44.000Z","average_A":69.0}
[21:01:01 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:56:45.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:50.000Z","average_A":9.0}
[21:01:01 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:55:30.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:55:35.000Z","average_A":47.0}
[21:01:02 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:55:42.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:55:47.000Z","average_A":76.0}
[21:01:02 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:55:54.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:55:59.000Z","average_A":54.0}
[21:01:02 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:55:27.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:55:32.000Z","average_A":63.0}
[21:01:02 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:56:36.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:41.000Z","average_A":34.0}
[21:01:02 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:55:45.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:55:50.000Z","average_A":31.0}
[21:01:02 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:55:39.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:55:44.000Z","average_A":72.0}
[21:01:02 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:56:18.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:23.000Z","average_A":36.0}
[21:01:02 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:55:57.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:02.000Z","average_A":5.0}
[21:01:02 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:56:48.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:53.000Z","average_A":63.0}
[21:01:02 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:56:21.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:26.000Z","average_A":44.0}
[21:01:02 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:56:03.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:08.000Z","average_A":95.0}
[21:01:02 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:56:33.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:38.000Z","average_A":89.0}
[21:01:02 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:56:27.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:32.000Z","average_A":30.0}
[21:01:02 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:55:33.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:55:38.000Z","average_A":40.0}
[21:01:02 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:56:24.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:29.000Z","average_A":77.0}
[21:01:02 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:56:15.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:20.000Z","average_A":8.0}
[21:01:03 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:55:27.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:55:32.000Z","average_A":63.0}
[21:01:03 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:56:36.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:41.000Z","average_A":34.0}
[21:01:03 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:55:45.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:55:50.000Z","average_A":31.0}
[21:01:03 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:55:39.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:55:44.000Z","average_A":72.0}
[21:01:03 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:56:18.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:23.000Z","average_A":36.0}
[21:01:03 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:55:57.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:02.000Z","average_A":5.0}
[21:01:03 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:56:48.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:53.000Z","average_A":63.0}
[21:01:03 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:56:21.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:26.000Z","average_A":44.0}
[21:01:03 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:56:03.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:08.000Z","average_A":95.0}
[21:01:03 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:56:33.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:38.000Z","average_A":89.0}
[21:01:03 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:56:27.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:32.000Z","average_A":30.0}
[21:01:03 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:55:33.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:55:38.000Z","average_A":40.0}
[21:01:03 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:56:24.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:29.000Z","average_A":77.0}
[21:01:03 INF] natsPullConsumer    {"start":"2024-04-02T18:56:15.000Z","end":"2024-04-02T18:56:20.000Z","average_A":8.0}
...

